# url rewriting and htaccess rule

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have rewritten a rule for URL rewriting but when i try to access the website admin panel, server shows me 404 error whereas front-end working with rewriting rule.

following rule are written

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

for admin panel

```
RewriteRule ^admin/page/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.html$ admin/page.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^admin/page/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(.*)$ admin/page.php?page=$1&$2=$3
```

For frontend

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
```

Though for front-end rule working fine and i can access the website using www.blabla.com/index.html. Written rule automatically convert the .php file into .html

Moreover these rule are working fine in my localhost and UAT server but on production server these rules do not work.

Any one can suggest what wrong i am doing or is there something with .htaccess or mod_rewrite where i can do some tweaks.

Suggest please.....

Comment: For debugging purposes, try putting `[L, R]` at the end of each of the admin rules, and see where they are redirecting you (the rewritten URL should appear in the address bar).

Comment: Also, give examples of what kinds of URLs are not being rewritten properly, and what you would like them rewritten as.

Comment: I have put the [L, R] at the end of each admin url but server shows internal server error. The objective is to convert the http://bla-bla.com/admin/page.php?page=login into http://bla-bla.com/admin/page/login though server redirect into the required url but shows 404 error. Surprisingly these rule are working fine in my localhost and on staging server.

Comment: Not at the end of the URL, I meant add them at the end of the admin rewrite rules after a space. Your rules seem to do what you want, after adding the R flag, just check what they are being rewritten to and see why that's a problem.

Comment: this is exactly what i did what but again 500 internal server has occured.

Comment: Then you should check your log files, you'll probably find more information there.

Comment: Yes if it's a 500 error there will be something in the server logs. There must be some syntax error. I checked the rules themselves - they seem to be fine.

Comment: Sorry, I had an extra space in the string I gave you, which led to the 500 error. Try putting `[L,R]` at the end of each rule, without the space.